# Search MySQL data via pop-up window

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am creating a job-card system for my automotive repair shop. My knowledge on `PHP` programming is basic but adequate for what I need.

I am writing a form to create a vehicle in the database. This is attached to a specific customer which I have created already. I want to be able to search for this customer during the vehicle creation process and attach the `customer ID` to the `vehicle` table.

I don't want a pop-up window as these are often blocked, but it can be a new window altogether. The data is then passed back to the original form where the vehicle is being created, then a submit button to enter the data into the database. I am using `PHP` and `MySQL`.

Comment: This question requires a complicated answer.  You're going to want javascript, ajax, etc. probably to do this.  Are you familiar with javascript?

Comment: Not really. I did not think it was so difficult. My customer table has primary ID. This would be attached to the vehicle table under the cell Customer. I wanted to search for the customer either by name or postcode, then pass this ID into the vehicle form before it is submited to database

Comment: Understood.  There's probably ways to do it with information that you can render / hide on the screen, but to be able to *search* would definitely require javascript.

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to use javascript. You could do it with a multi-step form submission process. It wouldn't be as slick, but it could be done.

Comment: Patrick, I don't mind if its not slick, must just be easy to write and practical. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you already have some sort of customer details page that displays information for a specific customer, yes? If so, on that page, I would add a link to an "add vehicle" page. That link would include the customerID in it. That customerID would then be read on addVehicle.php (or whatever) and either passed into a form has a hidden field or assigned to a `$_SESSION` variable. If I have time, I'll try to post a more complete answer, but that should give you an idea of one way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) in your frontend (html, javascript, css). Bootstrap has [modal window](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) which can be used as your solution, but you have to learn a lot (javascript, ajax etc.)

And autocomplete searching can be done with javascript [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) plugin.